# Should I rapid-cast the spider queen?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

The "Spider queen" is an attack/spell of the Witch doctor character in Diablo III.

It says "You may have one spider queen summoned at a time". And as soon as I cast a second one, the old one disappears / dies. So far so good.

The question: Is there any benefit of quickly casting a ton of them, or should I just cast one and wait? E.g. a benefit would be if the spell does damage on impact in addition to the damage-over-time.

Right now I just cast a lot of them, but only because I enjoy clicking. And due to my followers and pets, I cannot reliably determine the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think so. Spider queens don't make any damage on spawn and have to move to their target before dealing any damage.

Comment: I'd like to bring up a caveat that should you have the Grin Reaper it is worth to spam it.  The mimics aren't bound by the "one spider queen" at a time rule.

Comment: Relying simply on the attack function to spawn fetishes might end up being a bit counter productive. The queen has to move to the enemy and start an attack, so when you spam the button, she usually dies before an attack can be made. The next queen repeats the same process, and you end up doing little damage from your attack.

If you were using the spam attack strategy to spawn fetishes, or trigger any other reaction, I would suggest using an ability that is more spam-friendly, such as firebombs. You can still use the spider queen, just map a different button.